# Сравнение структуры таблиц

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток. Есть проблема: надо сравнить таблицы двух БД. Надо проверить, какими таблицами они отличаются и чем различаются сами эти таблицы. Есть ли для этого какой-либо удобный инструмент?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: когда то писал сам подобное. Ничего там сложного нет. Если пол часа гугления подходящего результата не дал - рекомендую написать своё. Плюс в том - что оно выйдет такое - какое вам нужно :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первая ссылка из [Google](http://www.google.ru/search?aq=f&gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=mysql+diff)

[MySQLdiff](http://www.mysqldiff.org/index.php)

> MySQLdiff is a little Tool to detect
> layout differences between two
> databases.
>
> Almost every developer knows the that
> changes of the database on the
> developement system have to be logged
> in order to update the live-system
> later on.
>
> To make this easier the tool MySQLdiff
> has been developed. Not as a real
> project but ...
>
> MySQLdiff will create a
> SQL-ALTER-Script which has to be run
> onto the live-system to 'patch' it to
> the state of the developement system.

PS Для Postgres я использую утилиту [apgdiff](http://apgdiff.startnet.biz/)

Comment: Спасибо, пока наиболее близкое решение).

Answer (score 0):

В MySql есть такая штука

```
Database: information_schema
```

Там содержатся все таблицы из данной БД, находи нужные и сравнивай :)

Comment: Это, конечно, прикольно, но **show tables** + **describe `table`** делают тоже самое.

Answer (score 0):

Это то что вы ищете

[dbForge](http://www.devart.com/ru/dbforge/mysql/studio/)

Comment: А на php что-нибудь есть? Мне со сравнения потом скрипт миграции писать...

Comment: Что мешает сразу написать на PHP скрипт проверки и все ?

Comment: Ничего. Но вдруг это решение уже есть? )  
Ну, или инструмент для облегчения задачи.

Comment: show table, desc table - что еще нужно то для "облегчения"? О_о

Или я не так понял - либо задача элементарна. Хотя я понимаю я тоже порой ленюсь писать что-то полностью сам :D

Comment: Для облегчения - это что-то типа сводной таблицы по таблицам БД и их полям, с кодом для переноса данных.

Comment: Я написал свой класс, если интересует могу выложить, там есть пара изянов но в целом работу свою делает. Класс на выходе дает sql файл с запросами для приведения двух баз к идентичному состоянию

Comment: @Arni, было бы здорово). А класс работает, если БД с разной структурой?